# How to resolve java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076) in android

Tags: android

Getting above exception when using `ThreadPoolExecutor` for parallel asyncthread execution.

The first time I request to the server which is long running process.
Meanwhile, I send one more request to the server which is executing correctly but first request which still has to run, but stopped after second request.

Comment: That is not an exception, only a line (possibly) responsible for it. Post the full stack trace.

Comment: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)

java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)


coming these both system errors .

Comment: There should be a lot more. This is what it should look like: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8217566/829571

Comment: 06-08 14:01:43.010: W/System.err(21348):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)

06-08 14:01:43.010: W/System.err(21348):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)