# Failed to configure parser

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I tried to solve this issue with help of other threads but I am getting this error again and again.[image: Error I am getting]

Code for focus_border_style_2:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle"
   android:thickness="0dp" >

   <stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/ApplicationBackground" />

    <corners android:radius="1dp" />

    <padding
    android:bottom="1dp"
    android:left="1dp"
    android:right="1dp"
    android:top="1dp" />

    <solid android:color="@color/greenName" />

    </shape>
```

This is the background I am applying to the edittexts and buttons where the problem is occuring.

StackTrace:

```
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #4: invalid drawable tag shape
at android.content.res.ColorStateList.createFromXmlInner(ColorStateList.java:148)
at android.content.res.ColorStateList.createFromXml(ColorStateList.java:131)
at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getColorStateList(BridgeTypedArray.java:301)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:987)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:629)
at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:625)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor6.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:82)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:128)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:806)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:809)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:400)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:332)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:332)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:517)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1584)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1309)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart$ReloadListener.reloadLayoutSwt(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1817)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart$ReloadListener.access$0(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1755)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart$ReloadListener$1.run(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1749)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3529)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3182)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

Comment: Is there any way we could have you post a [stack trace](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8217500/1167750) of the error that is happening?

Comment: OK . I included the stackTrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your stack trace, the error at hand appears to be:

```
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #4: invalid drawable tag shape
```

There may be additional issues happening here, but it's probably a good idea to take out the `android:thickness="0dp"` line in your `focus_border_style_2.xml` file.

This is because the [Drawable Resources for *Shapes* documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) indicates that `android:thickness="0dp"` should only be used when the Shape is a `ring` (`android:shape="ring"`) as shown under the following section:

> The following attributes are used only when android:shape="ring"
>
> `android:thickness` ...

After taking out the `android:thickness="0dp"` line, your code might look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners
        android:radius="1dp" />
    <padding
        android:left="1dp"
        android:top="1dp" 
        android:right="1dp" 
        android:bottom="1dp" />
    <solid
        android:color="@color/greenName" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/ApplicationBackground" />
</shape>
```

Comment: @user3788866 Glad to hear it!