# My clickable text always have this error "Unable to start activity ComponentInfo"

Tags: android

I have my login page where i have my login So it means i have a `button` for the Login and an `clickable text` for the redirection to the register page. My button works fine but when I'm clicking my clickable text `Unable to start activity ComponentInfo` error shows.

### MainActivity.class

```
package com.example.kun.carkila;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.kosalgeek.genasync12.AsyncResponse;
import com.kosalgeek.genasync12.PostResponseAsyncTask;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
final String LOG = "MainActivity";
Button btnLogin;
EditText etUsername, etPassword;
TextView tvRegister;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    tvRegister = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRegister);
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            HashMap postData = new HashMap();
            String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
            String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
            postData.put("username", username);
            postData.put("password", password);

            PostResponseAsyncTask task1 = new PostResponseAsyncTask(MainActivity.this, postData,
                    new AsyncResponse() {
                        @Override
                        public void processFinish(String s) {

                            if (s.contains("renterowner")) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Renter Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
                                startActivity(in);

                            } else if (s.contains("ownerrenter")) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Owner Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ownerhome.class);
                                startActivity(in);
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }


                        }
                    });
            task1.execute("http://carkila.esy.es/authenticate.php");
        }
    });

    tvRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(in);
        }
    });
}
}
```

My Register class is still empty though but still I cant manage to go there by clicking my textview. Thanks for the help. :)

### content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.kun.carkila.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/etUsername"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:hint="Username" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/etPassword"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etUsername"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:hint="Password" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Login"
    android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etPassword"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Register"
    android:id="@+id/tvRegister"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnLogin"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

### Manifest  ##

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.kun.carkila">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="@android:icon">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ListActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_list"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".DetailActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_detail"
        android:parentActivityName=".ListActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.kun.carkila.ListActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".InsertActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_insert"
        android:parentActivityName=".ListActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.kun.carkila.ListActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ownerhome"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_ownerhome"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".RegisterActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_register"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.kun.carkila.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

### Error

```
07-18 00:18:18.282 24312-24312/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.example.kun.carkila, PID: 24312
                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.kun.carkila/com.example.kun.carkila.RegisterActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                   at com.example.kun.carkila.RegisterActivity.onCreate(RegisterActivity.java:20)
                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1090)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643) 
                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

### RegisterActivity.class

```
package com.example.kun.carkila;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

}
```

Comment: Your Register class is still empty? What does it means? No layout associated?

Comment: ok good, could you please post the stacktrace?

Comment: It is simply the android log of the error. It look like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8217566/2442831

Comment: You are reading the logcat incorrectly... Look for the words "Caused by"

Comment: @Lino - O there, i edited it and I post my error which the "Caused by" is there.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, now go fix the NullPointerException in the code that you haven't posted here.... `Caused by:  java.lang.NullPointerException at com.example.kun.carkila.RegisterActivity.onCreate(RegisterActivity.java:20)`

Comment: Possibly relevant.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19078461/android-null-pointer-exception-findviewbyid

Comment: @cricket_007 - How can i fix the NullPointer in my case? I really have no idea. :(

Comment: It appears that the Register activity xml does not contain a Floating action button... I think I counted those lines correctly. FindViewById returns null. That's the problem

Comment: paste the xml for your resgister activity, the issue seems to in your register class xml, maybe you have deleted the fab button in your xml

Comment: @cricket_007 - That does the trick! Hahaha! I deleted the Floating Action Button. And now its okay. Thank you sir! :)

Comment: @SaravInfern - Its okay na I deleted my Floating Action Button on my .xml file and now I deleted it on my register.class. Still thanks for the concern. :)

Comment: @J.Deep can close this question

Comment: Welcome. Advice: Unless you know how to edit the generated Activity files from File > New, always write activities manually from scratch. Then you get less boilerplate code

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have declared the RegisterActivity in the AndroidManifest.xml file. Like this `<activity android:name="com.example.kun.carkila.RegisterActivity " />`

Comment: `android:name=".RegisterActivity"` is perfectly fine and in the question. Though the question was edited, if you don't have enough reputation to comment for more information, then it's best to move along to a question you can answer

Answer (score 0):

Delete the 
    `FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });`